# How much energy does Activity recognition API consume exactly?

Tags: android, battery, activity-recognition

I know that everyone keeps saying it's low but is there a way of getting real numbers instead of just saying "low" ? Like Fused location provider, it officially says it consumes 7.25% per hour if it's updated every 5 seconds in high accuracy mode. Why can't I seem to find any official given percentage about activity recogniton?

I need a documented result because I'm writing a scientific article and I can't simply use the term "low" energy consumption. If such estimation isn't provided in the official Google I/O does that mean that I'll have to just test it myself ?

Comment: `officially says it consumes 7.25% per hour` - and it is completely wrong since every device has different battery, different CPU, different GPS sensor, etc. It can't be 8.25 per hour on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to test it yourself. For activity recognition there's a lot of things in play, for example: hardware available to the API, not all device has all the sensors supported in Activity Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I've done several experiments in which I bypassed the battery and measured the power being drawn on a few devices, and I can tell you that even the same sensor draws a different amount of power on different devices. To complicate matters even more, some devices have a hardware FIFO, which saves power on these devices compared to those that don't, and it looks like ActivityRecognition API may be taking advantage of it on these devices.

I would recommend you choose a few different devices and just run some power experiments on them. Make sure you keep track of the API level used, since the hardware FIFO was only exposed in API 21+. Also, keep in mind that ActivityRecognition goes into a lower power state if it is still for too long, so find a way to keep it moving.